# Amcharts undefined values in small screen

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm getting some "undefined" values on the Amcharts when is rendered in a small window:
[image]

But the same graph, without reloading, if I move it to a bigger screen I got the values correctly:

[image]

Why is happening that?

This is some of the code of my graph:

```
funciones.chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",
    "precision":"3",
    "decimalSeparator": ",",
    "thousandsSeparator": ".",
    "legend": {
        "horizontalGap": 10,
        "maxColumns": 3,
        "position": "top",
        "useGraphSettings": false,
        "markerSize": 10,
        "marginTop": 20,
        "autoMargins":true,
        "forceWidth":true,
        "valueAlign":"right",
        "labelWidth":85,
        "valueWidth":85
    },
    "dataProvider": response,
    "synchronizeGrid":true,
    "valueAxes": [{
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "position": "left",
        "title": "Activos"
    }],
    "graphs": graphs,
    "chartScrollbar": {},
    "chartCursor": {
        "cursorPosition": "mouse"
    },
    "categoryField": "diahora",
    "chartCursor": {
        "fullWidth": true,
        "cursorAlpha": 0.1,
        "listeners": [{
            "event": "zoomed",
            "method": function(ev) {
                var value = funciones.chart.valueAxes;
                var uno = funciones.chart.dataProvider[value[0].start];
                var dos = funciones.chart.dataProvider[value[0].end];

            }
        }]
    },
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "axisColor": "#DADADA",
    },
    "export": {
        "enabled": true,
        "position": "top-right",
        "class": "export-main",
        "menu": [ {
            "title": "Exportar el gráfico a archivo de imagen",
            "label": "Descargar",
            "menu": [ "PNG", "JPG", "PDF" ]
        }]
    }
});
```

EDIT: hell! The data actually is badly made... I don't know why but in only 1 case the JSON comes with a blank array `[]` between the values:

```
[{"fecha":"2018-09-01","hora":"00:00:00","dia":1,"diahora":"1-00:00:00","cen_name":"AIHUAPI_______013","descripcion":"Rerversa 52ET2","activo_actual":"393.54786432893"},[],{"fecha":"2018-09-01","hora":"00:15:00","dia":1,"diahora":"1-00:15:00","cen_name":"AIHUAPI_______013","descripcion":"Rerversa 52ET2","activo_actual":"405.51075393844"},[], etc...
```

But in the rest are ok, as:

```
[{"fecha":"2018-01-01","hora":"00:00:00","dia":1,"diahora":"1-00:00:00","cen_name":"AIHUAPI_______013","descripcion":"Rerversa 52ET2","activo_actual":"179.64412533621"},{"fecha":"2018-01-01","hora":"00:15:00","dia":1,"diahora":"1-00:15:00","cen_name":"AIHUAPI_______013","descripcion":"Rerversa 52ET2","activo_actual":"169.2686290587"}, etc...
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data that is causing the problem as well as the contents of your `graphs` variable?

Comment: @xorspark the JSON has with all the values correctly, the data could be anyone, actually if I make a zoom the "undefined" appears and disappears randomly. Ok, I will add anyway the JSON in the end of my question

Comment: @xorspark well, the problem actually comes from the JSON, thanks for force me too check it...